# Internet Explorer 7 li link hover bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

Internet Explorer 7 only; FireFox, IE 8, Chrome works fine.

My left menu

http://box1.thegiant.ca/~cuisirama/index.php

If you hover any link the brackground becomes `transparent` how can i fix this?

Here is my CSS:

```
div.moduletable_mg { 
 border-top: 1px solid #9C907D;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}
div.moduletable_mg ul {
 padding: 15px;
 margin:  0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
div.moduletable_mg ul li {
 background: url(../images/menu-arrow.png) no-repeat left center;
 min-height: 15px;
 padding: 0px 10px;
 margin:  0px;
}
div.moduletable_mg a {
 /*display:inline-block;*/
 /*background: transparent !important;*/
 font-size: 14px;
 padding: 0px;
 margin:  0px;
 color: #483A22;
}
div.moduletable_mg a:link, div.moduletable_mg a:visited {
 text-decoration: none; 
}
div.moduletable_mg a:hover, div.moduletable_mg a:active {
 text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Oh lawwd the formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a 'hasLayout' issue. The problem actually is with your `#gdw2-mcleft` container. If I put a style on it to give that container 'layout', then it seems to behave as you desire (I used `zoom: 1` as my test, but you might desire to add some other style property that gives it layout).